# Usage and help mismatch on terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

I am unable to use some terminal command by just typing --help. I have to google it for its usage.
For example I have to get pid and name of the process matching the pattern
Help given by terminal by typing pgrep

> Usage: pgrep [-cflvx] [-d DELIM] [-n|-o] [-P PPIDLIST] [-g PGRPLIST]
>   [-s SIDLIST]  [-u EUIDLIST] [-U UIDLIST] [-G GIDLIST] [-t TERMLIST]
>   [PATTERN]

By googling I found the answer and the answer is(-l is not in terminal help)

> pgrep -l panel

Now I get the required result

> 5213 unity-panel-ser
>   5221 unity-2d-panel

So is there something I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use man-pages for full of options and examples along with descriptions. I have seen -l option from the man page.

Generally we all use man-pages.

try `man pgrep`